# How to interpret network request data listed in Firebug?

Tags: firebug

I have a Java application, which is run on Tomcat 7. In the application I want to control the 'Add Person' button, because I cannot add new person instances into my database via clicking it.

Thus, I learned that I should use Firebug to get information about the request data that is being sent to the server and what response data is sent by the server. I googled about Firebug but found almost nothing about how I should check network request and response data.

I loaded my application within Tomcat Manager, opened Firebug and reloaded the page. Here is how the *Net* panel looks:

[image: *Net* panel displaying request and response headers of GET request]

Then, I added name and country values, clicked the 'Add Person' button and got the following screen:

[image: *Net* panel displaying request and response headers of POST request]

[image: *Net* panel displaying POST parameters]

[image: *Net* panel displaying response body of POST request]

That's where I am stuck. I don't know what goes around here. How should I comment on whether the data sent to the server contains the person values or not?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the third screenshot displaying the *Post* tab the data you entered into the *Name* and *Country* fields is sent as POST parameters named `j_idt6:Name` and `j_idt6:country`.

You can find information about the [*Net* panel within the Firebug wiki](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel).